# Implementing moving animation

Tags: unity, c#

I faced the problem of attaching animation to the enemy. In the Animator window I added a "moveSpeed" (float) condition, so moving animation should turn on when moveSpeed is greater than 0.001. But after prescribing a reference to an Animator in the code, whatever I write further, a message pops up about the presence of compiler errors.
Here's my script:

```
public int health;
public GameObject explosion;

public float playerRange;

public Rigidbody2D theRB;
public float moveSpeed;

public Animator anim;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, PlayerController.instance.transform.position) < playerRange)
    {
        Vector3 playerDirection = PlayerController.instance.transform.position - transform.position;

        theRB.velocity = playerDirection.normalized * moveSpeed;

    }
    anim.SetFloat("moveSpeed") = theRB.velocity;
}

public void TakeDamage()
{
    health--;
    if(health <= 0)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

What exactly do I need to write for the condition to work and the animation to play?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What compiler error message do you get? You should always include the full text of the error — we don't write error messages just for fun; they contain vital information needed to track down the bug.

Comment: The message is "All the compiler errors should be fixed before you can enter playmode"

Comment: Which means you need to show us the other compiler errors in the console window.

Comment: It says "error CS1501: No overload for method 'SetFloat' takes '1' argument". This message shows when I write "anim.SetFloat("moveSpeed") = theRB.velocity" under the "if" statement in the update loop

Comment: Great. That belongs in your question — use the "edit" link at the bottom to ensure your question contains all information needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> error CS1501: No overload for method 'SetFloat' takes '1' argument"

This tells you you're using the `SetFloat()` method incorrectly, so you should [consult the documentation for how to use it correctly](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetFloat.html).

Here you'll see that the value to set needs to be passed as the second argument to the function, not as an assignment after the function call (you cannot assign something to a function call's result in C#)

So instead of writing invalid code like this:

```
anim.SetFloat("moveSpeed") = theRB.velocity
```

You would write:

```
anim.SetFloat("moveSpeed", theRB.velocity.magnitude);
```

Here I've used the `.magnitude` getter to transform the `Vector3` velocity into its scalar length, a speed.

Comment: Simple syntax errors like this don't require game development expertise to solve, so please get in the habit of reading your compiler errors and consulting the documentation to solve them faster. Post here when you have questions that can't be answered by the docs or Unity tutorials.